# Need help plotting all possible combinations of 2 variables as a grid

Tags: r, plot

I have a data set where one column is names, and the other is a series of colors. There are repeats in both columns. Along these lines:

```
X1       X2

Jon      Red
Brandon  Blue
Jared    Yellow
Aaron    Pink
Layton   Black
Colby    White
Brandon  Yellow
Aaron    Black
Zach     Red
Sean     Blue
Jared    Pink
Jon      White
```

I would like to plot these values as a grid, where on one axis are all unique names and hte other has all unique colors. Within the body of the plot, I would be marking which combinations of Name and Color have already occurred. Sort of like a bingo card. Rough example:

```
          Red    Blue    Yellow    Pink    Black    White

Jon        X                                          X
Brandon            X       X
Aaron                                X       X
Jared                      X         X
Colby                                                 X
Layton                                       X
Sean               X
Zach       X
```

Any ideas of how I would should approach this?

I don't have a lot of experience with plotting in R so I have been unsure where to start.

Comment: E.g. `library(ggplot2); ggplot(your_data, aes(X1, X2)) + geom_tile()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `ggplot2` approach to achieve your desired result:

```r
dat <- structure(list(
  X1 = c(
    "Jon", "Brandon", "Jared", "Aaron", "Layton",
    "Colby", "Brandon", "Aaron", "Zach", "Sean", "Jared", "Jon"
  ),
  X2 = c(
    "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Pink", "Black", "White",
    "Yellow", "Black", "Red", "Blue", "Pink", "White"
  )
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -12L
))

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(forcats)

dat |> 
  mutate(across(c(X1, X2), forcats::fct_inorder)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(X2, X1)) +
  geom_point(shape = 4, size = 4) +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  scale_y_discrete(limits = rev) +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solid answers posted by others, I managed to find my own way to fix the problem. Entering the data into the table() function returns a table exactly like I was looking for, which each Name/Color combo filled in with the number of occurrences that pairing makes in the data set.

```
> table(df[c("X1", "X2")])

              X2
              Red    Blue    Yellow    Pink    Black    White
    X1
    Jon        1       0       0         0       0        1
    Brandon    0       1       1         0       0        0
    Aaron      0       0       0         1       1        0
    Jared      0       0       1         1       0        0
    Colby      0       0       0         0       0        1
    Layton     0       0       0         0       1        0
    Sean       0       1       0         0       0        0
    Zach       1       0       0         0       0        0
```

From there I used heatmap() to plot which combinations had been used, and as a bonus it highlighted which have been used more than once!